# setstate inside render method - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that contains several questions. Some of the questions are having a set of sub-questions.
These are rendered using the following code.

```
    {
  Object.keys(this.props.moduleDetails.questions).map((questionInfo, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <QuestionAnswers
        questionInfo={this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo]}
        generateStepData={this.props.generateStepData}
        states={this.props.states}
        userEnteredValues={this.props.formValues}
        errors={this.props.errors}
        setQuestionAnswers={this.setQuestionAnswers}
      />
      {this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo].question_group &&
      this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo].has_grouped_questions ===
        1 ? (
        <div className="sub-questions">
          {this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo].question_group ? (
            <span>
              {this.renderQuestionGroup(questionInfo)}
              <input
                type="button"
                onClick={e => {
                  this.addQuestionGroup(questionInfo)
                }}
                value="Add"
                className="btn"
              />
            </span>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  ))
}
```

As you can see, the question groups are rendered using the renderQuestionGroup(questionInfo) method.

```
renderQuestionGroup(questionInfo) {
    let input = [];
    this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo] = (this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo]) ?
                    this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo]
                    : [];
    let answerId = this.props.formValues[questionInfo];
    let groupedQuestions = this.props.moduleDetails.questions[questionInfo].question_group[answerId];
    if((groupedQuestions != null && this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo].length == 0) || this.state.isAddPressed) {
        this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo].push(groupedQuestions);

    }
    input = this.display(questionInfo)
    return input;
  }
```

The problem here is that I cannot set state inside this method, as this method is called inside render method

Any idea on how to fix this?

Is there any alternate approach for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not set state inside render function because it will cause side effect.

What exactly happens is that each time you update state react calls render function, so if you will update state inside render function then it will stuck inside infinite loop.

In general, this should never happen; you should not be doing anything remotely related to modifying any component's state within a render function.

Answer (score 7):

You need to move your set state logic to

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (prevPros.prop !=== this.props.prop) {
          /* your setState logic*/
        }
      }
```

And then just use modified `state` in `renderQuestionGroup`.

Also never modify state directly with:

```
this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo] = (this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo]) ?
                this.state.groupedQuestions[questionInfo]
                : [];
```

Use `setState({groupedQuestions: [...groupedQuestions,updatedGroup })`

[from react set state docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.
>
> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState
>   and calls may be batched for performance gains.
>
> setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional
>   rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable
>   objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: componentDidUpdate is a better place.

Comment: Agree, always forgettind about will methods deprecation

Comment: As you can see, each question is passed in the renderQuestionGroup method. So how do i use the componentDidUpdate? Only in the render method, i get each question.  Any idea?

Comment: you already have new props in ```componentDidUpdate``` method. From them you can get all your ```question``` objects and update state if needed. There no difference in props objects that passed in ```render``` or ```componentDidUpdate```

Comment: Move all logic from ```renderQuestionGroup``` to ```componentDidMount``` and in ```renderQuestionGroup``` simple get display-ready data from already modified state

Comment: I have modified the code like you mentioned and it worked in most of the cases. One issue is that on every key stroke of text field handleChange method is invoked which will ultimately invoke componentDidUpdate method. So the same question groups gets rendered on every key stroke. How to fix this?

Comment: You should use `onBlur` event insted `onChange` to update state if you have heavy logic in `render()` method. Mark as answer if solution was helpful for your problem,  that would help others to quickly find right method to solve similar problems