# SetState from props dict in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I am stuck on solving a problem, set a state from props dictionary. My code looks like this:

```
this.state = {
    test: []
}
render() {
  this.props.data.map(function(item, key){
  this.setState({ test: data.name})
})
}
```

Is not working, does anyone have any ideas of how to do it. Thanks
   I've been doing some changes:

```
componentDidMount() {
     this.state.userData.then(data => this.props.getData(data.user["data"]). then(test => this.setState(test.test.map(item => item.name))))}
```

Still the state.test is empty.

Comment: never `setState` in `render`, use constructor, cDM, cDU ...

Comment: is there a reason why you want to move from props to local state? Why not work with the props instead? Are you planning to keep a local state inside your component (so update it, independent of the props?) If not, then just use the props instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setstate inside render method - Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189542/setstate-inside-render-method-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a state in the `render` function, this will cause an infinite loop.

**The correct way**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    test: props.data.map(item => item.name)
  }
}

render(){
  return (
    {this.state.test.map(item => {
      return (
        <p>{item}</p>
      )
    })}
  )
}
```

Comment: don't forget the `super()` call in the constructor. Also, why wouldn't props be enough, might be another question.

Comment: Thanks, I tried similar as you said @roc but I have an empty array, I think is because the data is not getting into the state from props, when I iterate through the props the data in render() the data is there. What could be the problem? I am using componentDidMount() to get the data to props.

Comment: @Michael can you please update the initial question so I can help you more ?

Comment: @Michael you need to loop through the props data and put them in the state. example: `componentDidMount() { this.setState({ test: this.props.data.map(item => item.name) }) }`

Comment: @RocKhalil is working thanks, but if I have a state like this [ this.state = { options: [ xdata : { data : [] } ] } I need the data to be in this.state.options.xdata.data

Comment: @Michael this is a little bit more complicated and needs a full example to be able to help; you’ll need to give us the sent props and expected result. However, I would suggest that you do it so you practice your react skills

Comment: @RocKhalil I am using a chart but that chart has the structure of: ` options: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: true,
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories:[]
        }
      },
      series: [{
        data: [400, 430]
      }],
    }` I have to pass the data into categories from componentDidMount() the data that I have so far is in test state is ['name1', 'name2'] i thought to do a const like this     const { categories } = this.state.options.xaxis;

Answer (score 1):

Try following this pattern will help you write clean code.

Also as can be seen that i have put the props directly within the constructor because it may be the case where the props are directly available to the component.

in case you want to make request and then after inject the props u can handle the same in the componentWillReciveProps or some Hooks method if your using react hooks

```
import React ,{Component,Fragment} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      //This can be done if the prop is props are available before component renders  
      test: this.props.data||[1,2,3,4]
    }
  }

  render(){
    let  {test} = this.state
    return(
      <Fragment>
        {test.map((it,i) => <div key={i} >{it}</div>)}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }


}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: done the example, my state is a bit different: this.state = { series: [{data: []}] } any ideas how I set the state in the data?

Comment: u can assign the state  to temp variable update that variable the do a setState back again eg:..........
let temp = this.state.series;-->do your stuff with temp then --->this.setState({series:temp})

Comment: I tried like this: const newSeries = []; this.state.userData.then(data => this.props.getUser(data.attributes).then( newData => newSeries.push( {data: newData.newData.map(item=> item.data)}))) this.setState{series:newSeries} but is not working, the series has empty list